# How to retrieve the rows between two dates in PostgreSQL?

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, date, postgresql-13

How to retrieve the row between two dates in PostgreSQL?

```
ID        START_DATE        END_DATE

1         02/03/2020       02/03/2021

2         05/04/2020       NULL
```

In the above example, `end_date` column is `NULLABLE`.

I want to retrieve the row using the `date` which falls in-between `START_DATE` & `END_DATE`. Endate `NULL` is considered it as `infinite`.

I am clueless on how to pass single `date` input to `two` columns and handle `NULL`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Postgres, you can use `infinity` for the end value.  I would suggest using that instead of `NULL`.  This is explained in the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html).

In the meantime, you can do:

```
date >= start_date and
(date < end_date or end_date is null)
```

I'm not sure if `end_date` is inclusive or not, so this might be `<=`.